# How do I execute a strut action on jsp page refresh?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts

I am new to struts FYI but could not find an solution or example to what I am trying to solve. I believe this is simple and I am just overthinking it.

I have a jsp page (index.jsp) that has links to other pages. One of my links is an action (actionViewLatest.do) to a java file that has some latest data list. It does its thing and then redirects to a jsp page (entryExample.jsp) that will populate the lists on this page. But on this page entryExample page I also can add entries/rows to the DB/tables. This has its own action and is working great.

So on this entryExample.jsp I want to have the page refresh once the user has entered their entry. This entry is now the latest and should populate  in the list. But since the lists get pulled on the action link on the index page it already has older data. In my code I have the page refresh in my if statement that checks to see if the user had filled all the data. So on refresh I will execute the action, my below code did not work :/ How can I refresh the page and execute the actionViewLatest.do action?

```
        <% response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);%>
        window.onunload = unloadPage;
        function unloadPage()
        {
            //function execute(frm){
            //frm.action="actionViewLatest.do";
            //frm.submit();
            //}
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. How to have an action execute on page load? Loading a page *does* execute an action, the action mapped to that page. Get the data in that action.

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was redirect my action of adding a new entry to the original action that will bring me to my jsp page and populate it with newer data. Originally I was redirecting it straight to the jsp page which would skip the pulling of updated content